# What do you call those "gifts" that are passed in a family from generation to generation?

Tags: single-word-requests

Example:

> Grandma left me her ring as a [...]

I thought of the word *souvenir* but I think it's more commonly used to refer to something that you buy in a gift shop.

Comment: How about *keepsake*?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A good word is **heirloom.**

There are others, but this should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a term that implies a formal act of leaving something by will , [bequest](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/bequest) may fit: ( from TFD)

> - (law) a gift of personal property by will